# pandas udf to split array of strings pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the following table

```
id | country_mapping
--------------------
1  | {"GBR/bla": 1,
      "USA/bla": 2}
```

And I want to create a columns that contains the following

```
id | source_countries
--------------------
1  | ["GBR", "USA"]
```

And I need this to be done via a pandas udf. I created the following

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.pandas_udf("string")
def func(s):
    return s.apply(lambda x: [y.split("/")[0] for y in x])
```

I thought this would work, because if I run this code in pure pandas it gives what i need.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([["GBR/1", "USA/2"], ["ITA/1", "FRA/2"]])
s.apply(lambda x: [y.split("/")[0] for y in x])
```

gives

```
Out[1]: 0    [GBR, USA]
        1    [ITA, FRA]
dtype: object
```

But when I run

```
df.withColumn('source_countries', 
              func(F.map_keys(F.col("country_mapping")))).collect()
```

It fails with the following error when i run the below:

```
PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'list' object'
```

I'm confused as of why - and how to fix my pandas udf.

Comment: Does it **have to** be in a UDF? what if standard built-in Spark function can handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that

> Currently, all Spark SQL data types are supported by Arrow-based conversion except MapType, ArrayType of TimestampType, and nested StructType.

See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#supported-sql-types) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/sql/arrow_pandas.html#supported-sql-types).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pandas_udf`, you can just use `udf` in similar way

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def func(v):
    return [x.split('/')[0] for x in v]

(df
     .withColumn('source_countries', F.udf(func, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))(F.map_keys(F.col('country_mapping'))))
     .show(10, False)
)

# +---+----------------------------+----------------+
# |id |country_mapping             |source_countries|
# +---+----------------------------+----------------+
# |1  |{USA/bla -> 2, GBR/bla -> 1}|[USA, GBR]      |
# +---+----------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I had exactly this function and I wanted to learn how to turn it into a pandas udf.

Comment: While udf is easier to implement, pandas_udf is much quicker.